# Android SuperSLiM: Margin between sections

Tags: android, superslim

I'm using the [SuperSLiM library](https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM) to recreate the agenda view from the google calendar app. The problem I'm having is to create a margin between sections. I tried putting a `topMargin` when it's the sections first position, but then the headers wouldn't appear correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. I give a boolean to my LineItem to say it is last and then apply a bottomMargin to it.

LineItem:

```
private class LineItem
{
    public int sectionFirstPosition;
    public boolean isHeader;
    public boolean isLast;
    public Item item;

    public LineItem(Item item, boolean isHeader, int sectionFirstPosition)
    {
        this.isHeader = isHeader;
        this.item = item;
        this.sectionFirstPosition = sectionFirstPosition;
    }

    public void setLast()
    {
        isLast = true;
    }
}
```

Settings last item:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
    {
        long header = item.get(i).getTimestamp();
        if (lastHeader != header)
        {
            if(mItems.size() >= 1)
            {
                mItems.get(mItems.size() - 1).setLast();
            }
            // Insert new header view and update section data.
            sectionFirstPosition = i + headerCount;
            lastHeader = header;
            headerCount += 1;
            mItems.add(new LineItem(items.get(i), true, sectionFirstPosition));
        }
        mItems.add(new LineItem(items.get(i), false, sectionFirstPosition));
    }
```

Set bottom margin:

```
    if(item.isLast)
    {
        lp.bottomMargin = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.section_margin);
    }else
    {
        lp.bottomMargin = 0;
    }
```